# Find equation of line given multiple 3D points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, interpolation

**Problem:**
Given the following points:
$A(0,1,3),B(-4,3,8),C(-5,4,9),D(-6,2,1)$
How can the function of the line $f(x, y)$ be determined?

**Attempts:**
I've tried looking for adaptations of LaGrange's interpolation formula, however the only applications are for 2 dimensional coordinates (it seems). I did find a [link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfLines.aspx) which looked promising; unfortunately, it looks like it only applies for two points?

Comment: The 4 points to not lie on a line.  However, as you bring up Lagrange's interpolation formula.  You could find and interpolating polynomials $f(t), g(t)$ such that $(x,y,z) = (t,f(t),g(t))$ would give you a parametric curve through the 4 points.  You would use the Lagrange formula on the $x,y$ pairs to find $f(t)$ and the $x,z$ pairs to find $g(t).$

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the equation of a line passing through four points, it does not always work out.

A line is determined by just two points. The other points may or may not be on that line.

However you can use the least square method to fit a line to your data which may or may not pass through the points.

The linear regression is a common process to fit a line through a set of points.